# Help file appered after a System Crash

Tags: bash, crash, symbolic-link

I just tried to open a very large .csv File which couldnt be opened in LibreOffice due to to many numbers of rows. I restarted my PC and now I got a File named 'help' in my home folder if i try to cd in it I get a error message which is as follows:

```
bash: cd: help: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I would appreciate every help.

Edit:
I removed the picture. And run the commands you suggested.

`ls -lh help` output is:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dennis dennis 4 Jul 15 15:40 /home/dennis/help -> help
```

`file ~/help`output is:

```
/home/dennis/help: broken symbolic link to help
```

`readlink -f ~/help`output is :

No Output produced

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -lh ~/help` and `file ~/help` and `readlink -f ~/help` to your question by [edit]ing it ... please copy and paste text from the terminal and do not add screenshots of the text.

Answer (score 1):

That file in its current state is both useless and harmless ... It is a symbolic link(*i.e. a shortcut*) to itself ... If a file is a symbolic link then it can just be only a link(*i.e. it cannot contain anything*) ... When a file is a symbolic link to itself then the file is useless and can be safely deleted.

As to why this symbolic link was created in the first place, I could speculate but, honestly, there is no way for me to know ... It could be a result of the system crash you had e.g. a backup file for LibreOffice Calc(*this is automatically done when editing a file ... it's part of auto-save or recovery*) ... or it might be something else(*e.g. a command or script or arbitrary GUI mouse clicks*) that did something like this:

```
ln -s help help
```

i.e. created a file that is named `help` and is a symbolic link to itself at the same time ... You could, however, try:

```
stat ~/help
```

Which will give you(*among other information*) the file's access permissions with **user**(*should be also the creator unless you changed the file permissions after its creation*) and **group**.

Comment: ok it definetly not came from the crash, because it was created at 3:40pm the crash occured somewhere arround 10pm. So i just didnt noticed it until after the crash. Still dont know where it came from so ill delete it and hope the best. Thank your for your help